# Polynomial Operations

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to write a program that constructs a polynomial from an input file. It reads in the polynomial and stores values into the class attributes "coefficient" and "exponent". E.g. coefficient = 2, exponent = 3 would result in 2x^3. There are a lot of annoying corner cases that must be handled when reading in the polynomial and outputting. (`operator<<` and `operator>>` functions) My main function thoroughly tests my polynomial.cpp. I believe one of my problems is coming from constructing the polynomial and as you may note, I'm also having trouble writing code for my derive function. Here is what I have:

```
#ifndef _POLYNOMIAL_H
#define _POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Polynomial {

 public:

  Polynomial();
  Polynomial(vector<double> iCoefficients, vector<int> iExponents);

  int Degree() const;
  double Evaluate(double x) const;
  Polynomial Derivative() const;

  friend Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial & p, const Polynomial & p2);
  friend Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial & p, const Polynomial & p2);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial & p);
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial & p);

 private:

  vector<double> coefficients;

};
#endif

#include "polynomial.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Default Constructor
Polynomial::Polynomial() { 
  coefficients.push_back(0);
}

// Constructor for a Polynomial
Polynomial::Polynomial(vector<double> iCoefficients, vector<int> iExponents) { 

  for (int i = 0; i < iExponents[0]; i++) {
    coefficients.push_back(0);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < iExponents.size(); i++) {
    coefficients[(Degree() - iExponents[i])] = iCoefficients[i];
   }
 }

// Returns highest exponent of the polynomial
int Polynomial::Degree() const { 

  return coefficients.size();
}

// Evaluates the polynomial at a particular point
double Polynomial::Evaluate(double x) const { 

  double result;

  for(int i = 0; i <= Degree(); i++) {
    result += pow(x, Degree() - i) * coefficients[i];
  }
  return result;
}

// Returns first derivative of the polynomial
Polynomial Polynomial::Derivative() const { //----------------------???

//   Polynomial result;

//   for(int i = 0; i <= Degree(); i++) {
//     result.coefficients[i] = coefficients[i] * (Degree() - i);
//   }
//   return result;
}         


// Returns polynomial object that is the sum of parameters
Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial & p, const Polynomial & p2) { 

  int d = p.Degree();
  int d2 = p2.Degree();
  Polynomial sum;

  for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d2; i ++) {
      sum.coefficients.push_back(p.coefficients[j] + p2.coefficients[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

// Returns polynomial object that is the product of parameters
Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial & p, const Polynomial & p2) {

  int d = p.Degree();
  int d2 = p2.Degree();
  Polynomial product;

  for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d2; i ++) {
      product.coefficients.push_back(p.coefficients[j] * p2.coefficients[i]);
    }
  }
  return product;
}

// Output operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial & p) {

  for (int i = 0; i <= p.Degree(); i++) {

    if(i == 0 && p.Degree() <= 1) {
      out << 0;
    }

    if (p.coefficients[i] != 0 && i != 0) {
      out << '+';
    }

    if (p.coefficients[i] != 0) {
      out << p.coefficients[i];
      if(i < (p.Degree() - 1)) {
    out << "x^";
    out << (i - p.Degree()) * (-1);
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// Input operator
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial & p) {

  char ch;
  int exponent;
  double coefficient;
  vector<double> coefficients;
  vector<int> exponents;

  while(isspace(ch) == false) {

    ch = in.peek();
    if(ch == '+') {
      in.ignore();
      in >> coefficient;
    }
    else if(ch == '-') {
      in.ignore();
      in >> coefficient;
      coefficient = coefficient * (-1);
    }
    else {
      in >> coefficient;
    }
      ch = in.peek();
      if((ch <= 'z') && (ch >= 'a')) {
    in >> ch;
    ch = in.peek();
      if(ch == '^') {
        in.ignore();
        in >> exponent;
      }
      else 
        exponent = 1;
      }
      else
    exponent = 0;

      coefficients.push_back(coefficient);
      exponents.push_back(exponent);
  } 

  p = Polynomial(coefficients, exponents);

  return in;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "polynomial.h"

using namespace std;

bool testPolynomial(const Polynomial& p, string expected);
bool testOperations(const Polynomial& p, int degree, double expected);
bool testInput(string s);


int main() {
  int errors = 0;

  cerr << "Note: Nearly all of the tests expect a working output operator. If a test fails, check that first" << endl;
  cerr << "Testing default constructor" << endl;
  Polynomial p1;   // test default constructor
  errors += testPolynomial(p1, "0");

  cerr << "Testing explicit value constructor" << endl;
  double c_arr[] =  {1.1, 2, 4, 7};
  int e_arr[] = {6, 3, 2, 0};
  vector<double> c(c_arr, c_arr+4);
  vector<int> e(e_arr, e_arr+4);
  Polynomial p2(c, e);
  errors += testPolynomial(p2, "1.1x^6+2x^3+4x^2+7");
  c.clear(); e.clear();
  cout << '1' << endl;
  Polynomial p3(c, e);
  errors += testPolynomial(p3, "0");
  cout << '2' << endl;

  cerr << "Testing operations" << endl;
  double c2_arr[] =  {-1.1, 2, -4, 7};
  int e2_arr[] = {4, 3, 2, 0};
  vector<double> c2(c2_arr, c2_arr+4);
  vector<int> e2(e2_arr, e2_arr+4);
  Polynomial p4(c2,e2);
  errors += testOperations(p1, 0, 0);
  errors += testOperations(p2, 6, 109.4);
  errors += testOperations(p4, 4, -10.6);

  errors += testPolynomial(p1.Derivative(), "0");
  errors += testPolynomial(p2.Derivative(), "6.6x^5+6x^2+8x");
  errors += testPolynomial(p4.Derivative(), "-4.4x^3+6x^2-8x");

  errors += testPolynomial(p1+p2, "1.1x^6+2x^3+4x^2+7");
  errors += testPolynomial(p2+p4, "1.1x^6-1.1x^4+4x^3+14");

  errors += testPolynomial(p1*p2, "0");
  errors += testPolynomial(p2*p2, "1.21x^12+4.4x^9+8.8x^8+19.4x^6+16x^5+16x^4+28x^3+56x^2+49");
  double c_arr3[] = {-1};
  int e_arr3[] = {0};
  vector<double> c3 = vector<double>(c_arr3, c_arr3+1);
  vector<int> e3 = vector<int>(e_arr3, e_arr3+1);
  Polynomial p5(c3, e3);

  errors += testPolynomial(p2 * p5 + p2, "0");
  errors += testPolynomial(p5, "-1");

  cerr << "Testing input operator." << endl;
  testInput("0");
  testInput("51");
  testInput("-1.1");
  testInput("3x^2");
  testInput("-5x^3-5");
  testInput("x^5+x-1");
  testInput("-x^4+2");

  return errors;
}

bool testPolynomial(const Polynomial& p, string expected) {
  ostringstream out;
  out << p;
  if (out.str() != expected) {
    cerr << "Test failed: expected " << expected << " got " << out.str() << endl;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

bool testOperations(const Polynomial& p, int degree, double expected) {
  if(p.Degree() != degree) {
    cerr << "Failed Degree operation" << endl;
    return true;
  }
  double result = p.Evaluate(2.0);
  if (fabs(result - expected) > 1e-5) {
    cerr << "Failed Evaluation operation" << endl;
  }
  return false;
}

bool testInput(string s) {
  Polynomial p;
  istringstream in(s+" ");
  in >> p;
  ostringstream out;
  out << p;
  if (out.str() != s) {
    cerr << "Failed input test. Expected: " << s << " got " << out.str() << endl;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: So... what did you do and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: You don't seem to implement the sum and the product correctly. Can you write down mathematical formulas for these operations, in some kind of algebraic notation, and compare with what you have? In unrelated news, do not put `using namespace std`in a header file.

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to require that you have two `std::vector`s with the exact same length.  Instead, have one `std::vector`, with both pieces of data in it as `pair`s (or `struct`s).  A pair of coefficient and exponent is a "term" in a polynomial, which might be a good name for the `struct`.  The nice thing about that abstraction is it is harder to make some of the errors you made in the above code if you always work with terms.  Write "Term GetNthTerm(int n) const", for example, and "size_t HowManyTerms() const", and much of your code starts being much easier to write correctly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. My explicit value constructor doesn't seem to be working correctly. I'll take a look at my sum and product functions.

Comment: Just a funny fact: it seems that you are trying to permit any name of the variable in the polynomial, not just `x`. But the letter `e` is special: `2x+2x^2` is OK but `2e+2e^2` is parsed as `200e^2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Polynomial::Degree()` function has an off-by-one bug; it should return `size()-1`

---

In order to convert the lists of coefficients and exponents, first find the maximal exponent; this will be the degree of the polynomial:

```
int degree = *std::max_element(iExponents.begin(), iExponents.end());
```

Then, initialize coefficients with this number of zeros (plus one, see above):

```
coefficients.assign(degree + 1, 0);
```

Then, set each coefficient, just like you did.

---

However, it is much better to use ascending order of powers/exponents! This way, you don't need to calculate `Degree()-i` all the time, you can use `i` instead.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < iExponents.size(); i++) {
    coefficients[iExponents[i]] += iCoefficients[i];
}
```

Note `+=` in the code above; it handles polynomials like `3x+4x+5x`, making that equivalent to `12x`.

---

Your addition and multiplication algorithms are completely wrong. You should first set the degree of the output polynomial, just like you did in the constructor:

```
Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial & p, const Polynomial & p2)
{
    int d = p.Degree();
    int d2 = p2.Degree();
    Polynomial sum;

    sum.coefficients.assign(std::max(d, d2) + 1, 0);
    ...
}
```

The rest should be easier, once you try to think about it.

---

After performing the addition, you might want to check for zero highest-degree coefficients; for example, when you add `2x^2+x+1` and `-2x^2+x+1`, you get `0x^2+2x+2`, which you might want to convert to `2x+2`:

```
while (coefficients.back() == 0)
    coefficients.resize(coefficients.size() - 1);
if (coefficients.empty())
    coefficients.push_back(0);
```

---

Derivative should be easy, once you get `operator+` and `operator*` right.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! You handled all of my questions. I'll get my code cleaned up and should be able to figure out addition multiplication and the derivative functions. Thanks again!